# catch seconds from current time of new audio

Tags: javascript

I have a question for you and I hope that you will help me.Once I wrote a new audio for ul li tags that is  with span for playing this music from data attribute and then I computed aud.currentTime and all what I only want it is how can I get in "if else" if current time of audio == 2 seconds?
I wrote this but it doesn't work

```
Math.floor(aud.currentTime);
if(aud.currentTime == 2){
alert('aud reached to 2 second');
}
```

I tried to compute value

Comment: Where is this code? Is it in an event handler or timer? [HTMLMediaElement: timeupdate event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/timeupdate_event)

Comment: no it is not both.it is just 
if(aud.currentTime == 2){
alert('aud reached to 2 second');
}
what I need to do?

Answer (score 1):

You need to put your code in an event handler or a timer. Here I use the [`timeupdate`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/timeupdate_event) event:

```js
let messagePrinted = false;
document.getElementById("aud").addEventListener('timeupdate', (event) => {
    if (messagePrinted) return;
    const aud = document.getElementById("aud");
    const playTime = Math.floor(aud.currentTime);
    if (playTime === 2) {
        messagePrinted = true;
        console.log('aud reached to 2 second');
    }
});
```

```html
<audio id="aud" controls autoplay muted>
  <source src="https://www.soundhelix.com/examples/mp3/SoundHelix-Song-1.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

Comment: thank you.I appreciated your attention to me.It works very well now and I'll never forget your help for it but I only didn't understand messagePrinted.What is it for?Can I leave it down or it is necessary?

Comment: Because the `timeupdate` event will get called multiple times per second. The `messagePrinted` variable just stops the message from being printed many times while the play time is between `2:00` and `2:59`. You can remove it and see the effect.